# How to monitor a EMR cluster whether it is terminated using cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-emr

I want to set alarm, when any EMR cluster is terminated(caused by internal errors), I know there is a "IsIdle" option, but my EMR clusters are designed to be persistent, so "IsIdle" is not really fit my case. Is there a health-check metric that I can used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) to send a "State Change" event to another service like an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function or an [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) topic.

To achieve this, open the [CloudWatch console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), in the navigation pane click on Rules > Create rule.

1. **Service Name**: EMR
2. **Event Type**: State Change
3. **Specific detail type(s)**: EMR Cluster State Change
4. **Specific State**: TERMINATED and TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS
5. **Targets**: Put the receiving service of your choice.

Here's an example of such an event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "8535abb0-f87e-4640-b7b6-8de000dfc30a",
  "detail-type": "EMR Cluster State Change",
  "source": "aws.emr",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2016-12-16T21:00:23Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "severity": "INFO",
    "stateChangeReason": "{\"code\":\"USER_REQUEST\",\"message\":\"Terminated by user request\"}",
    "name": "Development Cluster",
    "clusterId": "j-1YONHTCP3YZKC",
    "state": "TERMINATED",
    "message": "Amazon EMR Cluster j-1YONHTCP3YZKC (Development Cluster) has terminated at 2016-12-16 21:00 UTC with a reason of USER_REQUEST."
  }
}
```